# Java - Cannot write an image properly

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am using the following code to make 3 images 0.png, 1.png and 2.png but what happens is that three files are made 1, 2, 3 but they are not images and in picasa it is says that invalid file. Code:

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            Numbers.setText(""+i);

            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Flash_Cards.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("E:/Data/" + i));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Flash_Cards.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to: `ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("E:/Data/abc" + i + ".png"));`